# How do i select the rows (from the first to the last) only where a column changes its value?

Tags: mysql

So i have the following table in my database.

```
    Date        Time       Starea 
    2015-06-02  14:01:42    0
    2015-06-02  14:01:47    0
    2015-06-02  14:01:52    0
    2015-06-02  14:01:57    0
    2015-06-02  14:02:02    0
    2015-06-02  14:02:07    1
    2015-06-02  14:02:12    1
    2015-06-02  14:02:17    0
    2015-06-02  14:02:22    0
    2015-06-02  14:02:27    0
    2015-06-02  14:02:32    1
```

I need to select the rows **only** when 'starea' changes the previous value, taking in consideration that the first row of the query result **must** be the first row in the table.
For the above table my result query should look like this.

```
Date        Time       Starea 
2015-06-02  14:01:42    0
2015-06-02  14:02:12    1
2015-06-02  14:02:17    0
2015-06-02  14:02:32    1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: A cursor (prob a smarter way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with user variables.

First flag which `starea`s have changed in an inner query and select only those rows in the outer query:

```
  SELECT f.date, f.time, f.starea
    FROM (
      SELECT date,
             time,
             starea,
             @starea IS NULL OR @starea != starea AS changed,
             @starea := starea AS working
        FROM table1
        JOIN (SELECT @starea := NULL) init
    ORDER BY date, time
          ) f
   WHERE f.changed = 1 
ORDER BY f.date, f.time
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15bdc/6)

Comment: @RoscaSebastian Glad it worked for you.. kindly accept the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Have 3 columns in table. A

```
1. Id int auto_inc pk
2. datetime
3. Starea
```

Insert a row only if the Starea column has changed by first
SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Redundant for emphasis: dont insert if Scarea is the same value from select.

Solution is just a `select * from the_table order by id`

Data saved is not unnecessarily bloaty.

If u need attempt dates that can go in a separate logtable